# GO - Reading from Stdout in a loop

Tags: go, terminal

I'm new to ***GO*** and I'm trying to write a small utility in which I would like to execute commands in a loop and read their output. The code works but only the first iteration produces an output. I guess the assignment of stdout in the first iteration somehow blocks the subsequent use of stdout. Can someone explain me how to get around this problem?
(I simplified the code where the IP Addresses come from. I read them from a file but that's not relevant for the Problem.)

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var ip_addresses []string

func main() {
    ip_addresses = append(ip_addresses,"/server:192.168.100.1")
    ip_addresses = append(ip_addresses,"/server:192.168.100.2")
    ip_addresses = append(ip_addresses,"/server:192.168.100.3")

    for _, eachline := range ip_addresses {
        if strings.HasPrefix(eachline, "#") != true {

            c, b := exec.Command("query", "user", eachline), new(strings.Builder)
            c.Stdout = b
            c.Run()
            print(b.String())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `query` command do? Note that `Cmd.Run()` blocks and waits for the command to complete. If it does not end, your second iteration will not start. Also always check errors. `c.Run()` returns an error.

Comment: In this case Query returns the user logged in on the specified machine. The loop as well as the query command works correctly. I tested it with simple print and by removing the first IP entry. (The second get's then displayed, so it's definitely some problem with the stdout.) I read about some "pipe"ing regarding Stout but I did not understand those examples and It would be great if someone cold explain the workaround.

Comment: Your code looks correct. I replaced your command with "echo" (on linux) and it worked. It's either a go-version/OS specific bug in go itself, or there's something weird going on with your query command. As others have suggested, start by adding error-checking code.

Comment: I note that this can't quite be the code you've tested, since the imports are invalid. Are you sure you can reproduce the problem with this reduced snippet?

Comment: It's all a bit complicated... I write the code on a Manjaro machine and compile it for Windows. (I have no rights to install go on my work WindowsPC). The snippet works (after removing the unused imports.).

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the *exec.ExitError exception and log it to prevent the loop from breaking.

```
for _, eachline := range ip_addresses {
    cmd := exec.Command("ping", eachline)
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()

    if exit, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
        if status, ok := exit.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus); ok {
            log.Printf("Exit Status: %d", status.ExitStatus())
        }
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(stdout))
}
```

Comment: I tested some more and of course you all were right. It has something to do with the query command. Sorry for my assumption.
If I replace query with ipconfig, all three iterations produce the proper output.
I also included the error detection snippet from above but I still can't get query to work correctly. I chose 3 different remote hosts: one with a user logged in (OUTPUT should be the USER NAME), one where no one is logged in (OUTPUT should be "No user exists for *") and one where the RPC service is down (OUTPUT should be: "Error The RPC server is unavailable").

Comment: These are the outputs if query was started manually from the Windows CMD. Unfortunately I placed the one IP where there is a user as first and this is the one which produces an output.
Therefore I tought it had something to do with the iteration. Obviously not. The other two gives no output, altough it should print the above mentioned messages. The Exit Status (from the code sample) was in all three cases 1, so it ran properly. I still don't understand why certain outputs of query (which are clearly visible if started from a windows shell) are not passed to my program.

Comment: What do you mean by other two? Is there any error message you get when you debug?

Comment: As I wrote above, I selected 3 host PCs where I knew that they will produce 3 different answers. ("User Name","No user", "RPC server error"). These three outputs from query are displayed when I start query from the windows command shell. (They are in my opinion, not Error messages because the query command itself, works and runs properly. These are just the different answers from the remote PCs.) But only when a user is logged in, I do get the corresponding message inside my program. The other 2 messages ("No user" and "RPC Error") not come trough. I have an empty String in this cases.

Comment: Can you try to output using start and wait? like this: https://go.dev/play/p/0zmbLxBik0_1

Comment: Yes, u can put inside the loop.

Comment: I put your code inside the for loop but I put the query command instead of the echo. It executes the first query but only displays "DATE + exit status 1". It doesn't continue with the next iteration of the loop. Also, it doesn't display the actual output of the query command. If I test this code with the original "echo" "hi steve" command on my Linux machine, it runs perfectly fine. I know why I "don't like" Windows...

Comment: I switched to Win10 for you. Check err like my answer. Check it out: 
 https://go.dev/play/p/FkFuEhVSz2w

Comment: Thanks for testing on Win10! I copied your code into mine but unfortunately it still don't work. I still don't get 2 of the 3 possible Messages. Exit Status is always 1. I don't have enough reputation to start a chat here and I was reminded not to do endless comments here so I will look for help in the official GO Forum. Many thanks for your help!